# "extern string-literal declaration" within function scope

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, extern, linkage

from [[dcl.link]#2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#2) :

> extern string-literal declaration

the paragraph does not specify any special cases for declaration within a function scope, but following does not compile also :

```
void foo () { extern "C" int boo () ; }
```

from g++ output :

> error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

so is it a g++'s bug or i have missed something.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*linkage-specification*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#nt:linkage-specification) is part of [*declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:declaration) which is part of [*declaration-seq*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:declaration-seq) which can be part of a [*namespace-body*](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.def#nt:namespace-body) or a [*translation-unit*](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.basic).

Nowhere in the grammar is it allowed in a function, which uses [*block-declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:block-declaration), which is almost the same as *declaration* but is notable missing *linkage-specification*.